# How to connect an EC2 instance on aws to RDS MySQL database using Nodejs?

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-ec2, sequelize.js, amazon-rds

I created a RDS MySQL Database on aws and was able to connect it to my Node.js application via sequelize. But when I host the app to an ec2 instance, it gives the following error

```
 UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SequelizeConnectionRefusedError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
```

I can also connect it using the command line from the ec2 instance using

```
mysql -h mysql–instance1.123456789012.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -P 3306 -u mymasteruser -p
```

so its probably not a security issue. Here is the code I used to connect to the database:

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize("db-name", "root", "password", {
dialect: "mysql",
host: "db.hgjdfsaugc6h.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com",
port:"3306"
});
```

and to listen:

```
sequelize.sync().then(res=>{
 app.listen(7070);
})
```

I am fairly new to aws. What am I missing here?

Comment: A few ideas to test: Are all of the necessary security groups rules (inbound and outbound) for each element in the system properly configured? Is the RDS instance configured to be publicly available (or only from within a VPC)? Have you granted necessary privileges to your DB user on `localhost` as well as `%`:

Comment: @dusthaines I can connect to the db from my local machine i.e. from localhost and also from the AWS terminal. I do not think it is an issue with the security groups. The app runs properly on localhost but crashes when its run on the server. Is there any extra configuration needed for the hosted app to connect to RDS?

Comment: Based on my 3rd question above, there could be additional config required on the DB side. You included the `error` seen on the `node` side, but what do you see in the error logs on the RDS/MySQL side? There is probably more context and clues in those. In one of your code snippets it looks like your user is `root`, in another it looks like `mymasteruser`. Broadly speaking you should not use `root` as the default user for a public app for lots of reasons. If you run the following: `SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user WHERE user = 'mymasteruser';` is there a result having a `host` value of `%` ?